# How does prevState in new useState in React work ?? How does it store the value of previous state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know how to use prevState in new State, I want to know how does it actually works ?? How does this functionality works ?? why on putting in 'prevValue' in 'setFullName' function changes its value ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    let name = event.target.name;

    setFullName((prevValue) => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          firstName: value,
          lastName: prevValue.lastName
        };
      } else if (name === "lName") {
        return {
          firstName: prevValue.firstName,
          lastName: value
        };
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        {fullName.firstName} {fullName.lastName}
      </h1>
      <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} name="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input onChange={handleChange} name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a component is created (with `React.createElement`, or with JSX like `<App />`), React will see how many times `useState` is called in the component body, and will create an *internal* mapping of state indicies to state values. For example, with the following component:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [v1, setV1] = useState('a');
  const [v2, setV12] = useState('b');
  return <div>Text</div>;
};
```

When called, React will, internally, now have something like the following:

```
[ // array of all stateful values for this rendered component
  'a', // corresponds to the stateful value of the first useState
  'b', // corresponds to the stateful value of the second useState
]
```

These internal state values are changed when the state setter is called (eg `setV1`), and then when the component gets re-rendered, the new stateful values (coming from React internals) are then returned by `useState`.

When the state setter is passed a *callback*, eg, with your

```
setFullName((prevValue) => {
```

All that's really needed for this to work is for React to pass the current corresponding state value *in React's internals* as `prevValue`.

When state is set, the corresponding value in React's internals gets updated, but there may be other synchronous code that runs before the component gets re-rendered, and the new values (coming from React internals) get returned by the next invocations of `useState`. That's why using the callback form of the state setter sometimes gives different results - the callback argument always comes from React's internals, but the state value returned by `useState` only refers to the state *at the time the component was rendered*.

For example

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const clickHandler = () => {
  setCount(count + 1); // sets the state in React's internals to 1
  setCount(count + 1); // sets the state in React's internals to 1, not 2;
                       // because `count` still refers to the initial value of 0
};
```

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const clickHandler = () => {
  setCount(count + 1); // sets the state in React's internals to 1
  setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1); // sets the state in React's internals to 2
                                        // because `prevCount` comes directly from React's internals
};
```

But, for your code here, because multiple state changes are not occurring in the same render, there's no need to use the callback form - feel free to use the outside `fullName` identifier instead of using the `prevValue` and a callback.

Comment: Thank You very much. You explained it very clearly !!